# Where is my SQLite file?

Tags: android, sqlite

Using the ADT, I created a SQLite database as follows:

```
    SQLiteDatabase myDB;
    myDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase("ddk.db", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    myDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Tablezz (Field1 VARCHAR, Field2 INT(3));");
```

I cannot find a file called `ddk.db` anywhere on my computer (PC/Windows 7). The app seems to find it okay. Why can't I?

Thanks.

Comment: Not for lack of trying. Apparently the word "emulator" is key to finding this answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my applications, my SQLite files end up at:

```
/data/data/<package_name>/databases/<db_name>.db
```

I'm not sure if this is default for every IDE or not, but I also used ADT.